# How do I move a let variable to a separate hypothesis?

Tags: coq

In Coq, as a simplified example (using `False` to ignore the conclusion),

```
Theorem example
    (f : nat -> bool)
    (g : bool -> bool -> bool)
    (cmplx :=
      let a := f 0 in
      let b := f 1 in
      g a b
    )
    : False.
```

I want to take the let variables `a` and `b` out of the scope of `cmplx` and make them into separate hypotheses, like

```
Theorem example
    (f : nat -> bool)
    (g : bool -> bool -> bool)
    (a := f 0)
    (b := f 1)
    (cmplx := g a b)
    : False.
```

This is easy to prove in specific cases, e.g. with using `change` directly, or if you can `pattern` the expressions to catch how the let variables are used,

```
Theorem let_up {B C D} (b : B) (c : B -> C) (d : C -> D)
    : let r := let a := b in c a in d r = let a := b in let r := c a in d r.
Proof.
  apply eq_refl.
Qed.

Theorem example : ...
Proof.
  revert cmplx.
  (* manually patterning *)
  change (let cmplx := let a := f 0 in (fun a => let b := f 1 in g a b) a in (fun _ => False) cmplx).
  rewrite let_up.
  intros.
```

Though, this raises `a` and could be done similarly for `b`.

Is there a tactic to do this generally?  Or, a larger `Ltac` I could write to handle it automatically?  I have a more complex function with many lets that I want to act on separately, so I want to split them out in this way.  I can just `change` it, but it's long enough that that would be annoying.  I also tried things like

```
lazymatch goal with
| H := let _ := ?b in _ |- _ => idtac H "has" b
end.
```

but, it doesn't seem to let you match the `in` clause, probably due to non-free variables.

That is, I want to be able to say something like

```
let_up cmplx a
```

to raise `a` out of `cmplx`.

Edit 1:
`g` is a more complex function, so `simpl` and similar would make it very large and unreadable.  I only want to remove the top `let` and not make other changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
set (a:=f 0). 
set (b:=f 1). 
fold a b in cmplx.
simpl in cmplx.
```

`set` defines new variables in the context.

`fold` replaces a term with a definition that is definitionally equal.

`simpl` can help to "get rid of" let bindings.

EDIT. Ah, now I see you want a tactic that does this automatically.

Comment: I tried some variants of that without luck (but didn't say in my post).  Even after I have `let a := a in ...` I wasn't able to remove it without `change`.  `simpl` changes the rest of the expression too much in my case.  I've edited my question to say that `simpl` doesn't work.  Otherwise, I could just `simpl` in the first place.

Comment: More directly, if there's multiple `let`s, then `simpl` would only allow capturing the first one before inlining the rest (thus missing `b`).  So, it's important to not change the rest until they're matched and raised out.  Also, variations of `context` matches only seem to find the first, so it doesn't give you all of them.  Basically, I'd want something like `cbv zeta 1` to only zeta the first let, but not the rest.